# Change outer double quotes into single quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following div:

```
<div class="test" data-layer-promotion-view="{"row_type":"row-type-3-dynamic-smart","row_id":"home-page-row-01-widget","column_id":1,"id":"jj-storefront-hero-rethinking-denim","name":null,"creative":"/on/demandware.static/-/Library-Sites-bestseller-content-library/default/dw871109fc/jackjones/store-assets/w09/smart-widget/hero/rethinking_denim-dk.jpg"}"></div>
```

I would like to change the outer set of double quotes into single quotes using jQuery or JavaScript, since I don't actually have access to change the HTML.

This needs to happen for all `data-layer-promotion-view` attributes in the DOM. Can this be done?

Comment: The HTML itself is invalid, so changing the attribute in JS is irrelevant to the problem

Comment: Not really cause the data-layer-promotion-view is send as JSON to wherever it is needed, put in order for me to be able to do some magic with (data.key) I need the outer double quotes to be single quotes, but I do not not have access to change this in the HTML.

Comment: Then you will have to store the value in a format other than JSON. The issue I alluded to above is that the HTML is invalid due to the mis-matched quotes, hence it will be changed by the renderer and you will not be able to access the value in JS.